# How to set environment variables on Heroku for Node app and connect to the PostgreSQL database?

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, config

I know there are the same/similar questions on stack overflow and I have read the documentation too-I just still don't understand ANYTHING- how to set those variables and WHERE!! to set them.

My env/production.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    "DATABASE_URI": process.env.DATABASE_URI,
    "SESSION_SECRET": process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    "TWITTER": {
       "consumerKey": process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
       "consumerSecret": process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
       "callbackUrl": process.env.TWITTER_CALLBACK
    },
    "FACEBOOK": {
        "clientID": process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        "clientSecret": process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "callbackURL": process.env.FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL
    },
    "GOOGLE": {
        "clientID": process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        "clientSecret": process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "callbackURL": process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
    },
    "LOGGING": true
};
```

In my env/development.js file I set the variables (linked to my PostgreSQL/localhost/xxx). Do I need to set them in Heroku for all (Google, Facebook etc.) or just for the database, since I had to create one with Heroku? Do I leave the link to my local database in my development file and link to the Heroku database separately?

I don't even know if I am supposed to do it from my command line?! In the documentation it says: Heroku config:get CONFIG-VAR-NAME -s  >> .env
so would it be Heroku `config:get CONFIG-NAME OF MY HEROKU DATABASE -s  >> .env` ?

I'm deploying for the first time and so confused! Help :)

Comment: It can be done in UI, In heroku dashboard for the app, go to settings  and set up you environmental variables

Comment: Okay found it in settings! Thank you!! Also, for facebook and google-would I set the callbackUrl then? Also, as I understood, I am also suppose to set the NODE_ENV=production -could you explain how?Thank you!

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 53):

According to [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) you could use `heroku CLI`

```sh
heroku config:set DATABASE_URI=database_uri_here --app your-app-name
heroku config:set SESSION_SECRET=session_secret --app your-app-name
```

or you could use UI [https://dashboard-classic.heroku.com/apps/{your-app-name}/settings](https://dashboard-classic.heroku.com/apps/%7Byour-app-name%7D/settings) and provide the same variables via web interface, as I mentioned in the above comment

`NODE_ENV=production` is not treated specially by `heroku`, so you do need to provide it as well as any other env variable

Answer (score 36):

```
heroku config:set $(cat .env | sed '/^$/d; /#[[:print:]]*$/d')
```

set your config from .env file

Comment: `Session is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar.`

Comment: Worked for me! 

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Would be great if someone can explain what this sed command does exactly

Comment: Very efficient! - Is there a way to prevent the values print to screen?

Comment: 'sed command': https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/

Comment: You need to also specify the App to target. heroku config:set $(cat .env | sed '/^$/d; /#[[:print:]]*$/d') --app=your-app-name

Comment: This works only on bash cli. It can be run on git bash too

Answer (score 5):

Especially database connection variables will not work through Heroku env variables.
I would suggest using [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and set variables to the file by installing [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and then use bash:

```
heroku login
heroku run bash -a app_name
```

create `.env` file if it is not there and add values to it

```
touch .env
echo "ENV_VAR=value" >> .env
```

confirm the entry in a file

```
cat .env
```

Answer (score 2):

**Heroku now automatically sets the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable when you add the PostgreSQL add-on**

This variable can then be seen just next to the other environment variables, possibly manually defined, under:

- Settings
- Config Vars

That added variable already contains secret authentication information, so you should just use it as is.

**How to get it working with Sequelize**

I just managed a working solution with Sequelize as mentioned at: [Deploy FeathersJS App on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270219/deploy-feathersjs-app-on-heroku/66723974#66723974) with Sequelize, you basically just need to do:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    protocol: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            require: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
});
```

as mentioned at: [Can't connect to heroku postgresql database from local node app with sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687546/cant-connect-to-heroku-postgresql-database-from-local-node-app-with-sequelize)

Answer (score 1):

Loggin in Heroku CLI:

```
heroku login
```

list all apps:

```
heroku apps
```

Massive export of environment variables

```
cat .env | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs heroku config:set -a your_app
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

`$ heroku login`

then edit all config variables:

`$ VISUAL="emacs" heroku config:edit -a <app_name>`

This opens emacs where you can copy/paste the entire `.env` content. Then save and quit (Ctrl+x Ctrl+s, Ctrl+x Ctrl+c).