# How to hide API key and still run heroku app?

Tags: reactjs, api, api-key

I'm trying to understand how I can hide API keys and still run my Heroku projects in the browser. I understand how I can add an environment variable within a `.env` file and then add the `.env` file to the `.gitignore` file which successfully hides the file containing the key from GitHub. However, when I try to push the latest commit from the remote repo in order to get the latest version of the project with Heroku, the hosted project does not work because it does not see the key that it needs to use.

Once I figure out how to get the hosted Heroku project to work with the latest GitHub commit that hides the key, I would like to figure out how to configure the key to only work with the domain of my project and not work with any other domain address since I know that it's still possible to find the key within the source code if it's not hidden using a backend server. I haven't gotten around to learning about backend so I would want to learn how to make the key only work with my domain. Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables on heroku for nodes app and connect to the postgresql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119964/how-to-set-environment-variables-on-heroku-for-nodes-app-and-connect-to-the-post)

Comment: You set the variables via cli directly, no need to store them in any file this way

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to use any backend and this link talks about how to do it with backend. I'm looking for a solution that only uses front end tactics.

Comment: Could you explain further for me?

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is set the API key as a config var in the settings section of your heroku dashboard by going to your heroku app, clicking on Settings and then scrolling down the config vars.

Alternatively, you can do this through the heroku cli with heroku config:set. Check out the [heroku docs here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) on both of these options

**Update**: To access the config var, you use the same syntax as other environmental variables.

For example, if you set a configuration variable called `API_KEY` with the value being ABCDEFG, the way you'd access it in your code (with react):

```
var myKey = process.env.API_KEY;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try this when I get the chance.

Comment: No problem. Updated the answer to show how to access the env var in react as well ^

Comment: Hey so I just got around to trying it. I've added the env var in the heroku dashboard and the key wasn't working when I used process.env.API_KEY and committed the new code. Later on I also tried making a .env file and typing `API_KEY="the_key"` and then using process.env.API_KEY to call that variable in localhost but still it returns undefined.