# How to connect via SSL to sequelize DB

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can't seem to find any documentation for **SEQUELIZE.JS** on how to use a CA.crt in order to enable connection to my database sitting on a remote server.

I figure its something in the options but I can't seem to figure it out

I have tried

```
{
 'ssl': true
 'dialectOptions':{
   ssl: {
     ca: 'path/to/ca'
   }
 }     
}
```

and a few other things but nothing seem to work for me.

Can anybody help me?

Edit:

Here is an error i get when using the ca thing

```
error connecting to db { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at TLSSocket.<anonymous>
```

Comment: In addition to my below, just a quick remark. You need to pass all 3 components, 2 certs and key file in some form.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687546/cant-connect-to-heroku-postgresql-database-from-local-node-app-with-sequelize

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you don't mention the backend DB of choice, I'll give a `mysql` sample and how I'd suggest you go about it.

First, confirm the connection using the `dialect` directly, so for `mysql2` supplying variables as necessary:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbVars.host,
  user: dbVars.user,
  database: dbVars.database,
  password: dbVars.password,
  ssl: {
    key: cKey,
    cert: cCert,
    ca: cCA
  }
});
```

Once that connection is confirmed, move it to Sequelize as:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbVars.database, dbVars.user, dbVars.password, {
  host: dbVars.host,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      key: cKey,
      cert: cCert,
      ca: cCA
    }
  }
});
```

Note: loading the certs properly was a learning curve and required a direct `import` using a `raw-loader`. Example:

```
import cKey from 'raw-loader!../certs/client-key.pem';
```

Comment: `fs.fileReadSync` works just as well for me to read the .pem files.

Comment: Per [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) it is `fs.readFileSync`.

Comment: How do I get `cCert` and `cCA`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142239/mark)'s answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367384/2860309), I was able to connect to a Postgres RDS instance from a Node.js Lambda function as follows:

```
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(POSTGRES_DATABASE, POSTGRES_USERNAME, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, {
            host: POSTGRES_HOST,
            port: POSTGRES_PORT,
            dialect: 'postgres',
            dialectOptions: {
              ssl: {
                // CAUTION: there are better ways to load the certificate, see comments below
                ca: fs.readFileSync(join(__dirname, 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem')).toString()
              }
            }
          });
```

(Obviously this required the PEM file to be available, see [Using SSL/TLS to encrypt a connection to a DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html))

Comment: Read a file, to finally set it as string?  just copy the pem content into an ENV VAR and use it.

Comment: You may be right, but that's not really a central feature of the example :)

Comment: bad practices propagation, is the copy/paste example. Hope anyone read the good alternative. Regards.

Comment: @NingaCodingTRV fair point, i've updated the example to point here. another alternative is loading the file outside of the handler so that it's available for the invocation context.