# Deploy FeathersJS App on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, docker, heroku, feathersjs

I'm trying to deploy my [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/) web app on heroku, and since feathers is simply an express wrapper I thought it was like deploy an ordinary node app. I got the "npm start" script on my package.json, I added heroku remote to my git repo and when I push heroku run "yarn install" and the "npm start" script. But just when the app start, an error occurs:
[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo40j.png)

I can't figure out what happen, any suggestions?
Maybe I could dockerize my app, someone could help me to find the proper implementation?

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as Express but the generated application will by default use [feathers-configuration](https://github.com/feathersjs/configuration) to pull in your application settings. From the error message it looks like you are not providing a proper `NODE_ENV` environment variable which has to be set to `production` when deploying to Heroku.

Comment: Hi Daff, thanks for your answer, but I still have the problem. I set the NODE_ENV env var to production in Heroku but when I deploy I see this: "WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names" and the above error still occurs.

Comment: Are you checking in an deploying the `config/` folder?

Comment: it's embarassing, I had gitignored the config folder. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Daff shouldn't config direct be ignored? Atleast the production config should be.

Answer (score 1):

**Working port of feathers-chat app to Heroku PostgreSQL via Sequelize**

I got a port of the hello world https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat running on Heroku right now!

- source: https://github.com/cirosantilli/feathers-chat/tree/sequelize-pg
- live until it breaks: https://cirosantilli-feathersjs-chat.herokuapp.com/

**Key source changes**

Set `'postgres'` to the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable `config/production.json`:

```
+  "postgres": "DATABASE_URL"
```

Heroku also exports `PORT` which was also already in that file before my patch.

Pass `dialiectOptions` to the DB connection as per: [Can't connect to heroku postgresql database from local node app with sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687546/cant-connect-to-heroku-postgresql-database-from-local-node-app-with-sequelize)

```
+  const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionString, {
+    dialect: 'postgres',
+    logging: false,
+    define: {
+      freezeTableName: true
+    },
+    dialectOptions: {
+      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687546/cant-connect-to-heroku-postgresql-database-from-local-node-app-with-sequelize
+      // https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js
+      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965011/sequelizeconnectionerror-self-signed-certificate
+      ssl: {
+        require: true,
+        rejectUnauthorized: false
+      }
+    }
+  });
```

**Key Heroku settings**

- enable the PostgreSQL Heroku add-on with:

  ```
  heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev-
  ```

  This automatically sets the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable for us.
- in config/production.json edit `host` to your correct value
- in the Heroku app Settings, set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production`

Bibliography:

- https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1647

Answer (score 0):

try set "NODE_CONFIG_DIR" to  "app/config/"

Comment: just for myself in the future, this worked for me by setting app.js: process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = path.join(__dirname, "../config/");