# SequelizeConnectionError: self signed certificate

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, backend

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL Database that I've set up in Heroku.

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");

// DB Configuration
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: "[won't show db]",
  username: "[won't show username]",
  password: "[won't show password]",
  host: "ec2-54-221-195-148.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
  port: 5432,
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: true,
  },
});
```

And this is what I am getting as the output:

> SequelizeConnectionError: self signed certificate

Answer (score 129, accepted):

This is due to an (accidental) breaking change in `node-postgres` version 8 (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2009)).

The solution is to pass `rejectUnauthorized: false` to the `sequelize` connection parameters inside of `dialectOptions`>`ssl`, as [described here by GitHub user jsanta](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2009#issuecomment-556020509), bypassing the SSL certificate check (which is okay when connecting to a trusted server over a secure connection such as on your local host or between your own servers in the same network):

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: "xxxxx",
  username: "xxxxx",
  password: "xxxxx",
  host: "xxxxx",
  port: 5432,
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false // <<<<<<< YOU NEED THIS
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: this works with "sequelize": "^5.21.10",
        "pg": "^8.2.1",

Comment: Seriously, does the sequelize team understand published APIs at all? Like... AT ALL? (sigh)

Comment: FYI for sequelize 6.3.5, I had to do: `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }`.

Comment: @WithoutATowel I answered your question already. Kindly check and upvote if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: False alarm! I had a typo. This fix works :)

Comment: For over an hour I couldn't figure out why this solution didn't work for me. It turns out, I had "rejectUnauthorized: false " outside of "ssl" in "dialectOptions". If anyones still having issues, make sure you have it correctly nested.

Comment: Though this works, if you are using rds you can go with more secure approach by downloading right certificates, you can find instructions here https://medium.com/soluto-nashville/best-security-practices-for-amazon-rds-with-sequelize-600a8b497804

Answer (score 9):

in my case none of the above works, I use the connection string method to apply pg configurations, so I set the query param `sslmode=no-verify` and I got it works

example

```
postgres://myuser:mypassword@myhost:5432/mydatabasename?sslmode=no-verify
```

Comment: Yes, in my case that's the case as well. Anyone knows why we have to do this?

Comment: In my case this was the solution, my stack is kubernetes in digitalocean, managed database, and I created a database and a user that were not the default ones

Comment: It happens because you use `uri` parameter for defining the connection, not the `pg` object parameter. PostgreSQL accepts several values for the `sslmode` parameter explained here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html. It is used for defining our acceptance level for unverified certificates.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me (on sequelize config.json file):

```
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": {
        "require": true,
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, in the `config.json` file

```
  "development": {
    "username": "dummy",
    "password": "dummy",
    "database": "dummy",
    "host": "dummy",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions":{
      "ssl": {
        "require": true,
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice but this is the exact same solution I posted, just without explanation... Instead it refers to a file not everyone will even have.

Answer (score 0):

I am accessing the db through Sequelize and the other options weren't working. To resolve this, I used this note and set a config var.

Alternatively, you can omit the ssl configuration object if you specify the PGSSLMODE config var:

heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#connecting-in-node-js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

add the following in your code...

```
dbRDS=false
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? It looks like a variable assignment but this alone won't have any effect...