# "Self signed certificate" error on Heroku running sequelize db:migrate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

I have a Node / Express app with a Postgres database that functions perfectly on my local machine, but I'm struggling to get it up and running on Heroku. The problem occurs after I push to Heroku -- which builds successfully -- when I then try to run `heroku run sequelize db:migrate`. The error is:

```
ERROR: self signed certificate
```

#### My setup:

- Node v15.12.0
- Postgres database ("Heroku Postgres" add-on)
- pg v8.5.1
- sequelize v6.6.2
- sequelize-cli v6.2.0

#### My Sequelize connection parameters:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "XXXXXX",
    "password": "XXXXXX",
    "database": "party_playlist",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": {
         "require": "true",
         "rejectUnauthorized": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Many posts speak to this issue (GitHub: [1](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2009) | [2](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12083) | [3](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5671), StackOverflow: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965011/sequelizeconnectionerror-self-signed-certificate) | [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350186/how-to-solve-the-database-connection-error-sequelizeconnectionerror) | [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691212/nodejs-and-express-error-self-signed-certificate)), and most point to pg v8 as being the root of the problem; however, none of the recommended solutions have worked for me.

#### What I've tried so far:

1. Adding `rejectUnauthorized: false` to my Sequelize connection params
2. Adding `ssl:true` to the config outside of dialectOptions
3. Adding `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` to my Heroku environment variables
4. Adding `PGSSLMODE=no-verify` to my Heroku environment variables
5. Toggling Heroku's `Automatic Certificate Management` feature on/off
6. Rolling back to pg v7 (various subversions)

1-5 have no effect, and rolling back to pg v7 breaks the app (locally, any attempted reads/writes to the database hang with no error message; on heroku, the db:migrate command runs without an error message, but the db isn't updated). I assume that pg v7 is incompatible with my Node version or some other package version in my project, but I have no idea how to figure out what a compatible version set would be other than by trial and error, which isn't feasible. Also, as a side note, this is a hobby project so I'm not worried about MITM attacks.

Interestingly, I'm able to connect to my Heroku database just fine when I run `heroku pg:psql`!

Any ideas how I can fix this one? Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965011/sequelizeconnectionerror-self-signed-certificate) and the accepted answer there worked for me. I observed that we have the same versions of pg and sequelize but not same version of node. I am on v14.8.0. I suggest you use [nvm](https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b) to switch to that version and try again as I have observed that node versions with odd numbers(like 13,15) often give issues(my observation might be wrong though).

Comment: Thanks camelCase! Sorted it out... my boolean was wrapped in some extra quotes. Appreciate you taking a look!

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice. Cool though.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
"ssl": {
    "require": "true",
    "rejectUnauthorized": "false"
 }
```

Should have been this:

```
"ssl": {
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
 }
```

Noting the quotes around the boolean.

Dumb mistake but I'll leave this up in case anyone else makes the same error someday.